# Nilpotent degree $2$ 'families' of $4\times 4$ matrices

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

$\def\b{\begin{bmatrix}}\def\e{\end{bmatrix}}$

Are $\b0&0&a&b\\0&0&c&d\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\e$ and it's transpose, $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb C$ the only nilpotent degree $2$ 'families' of matrices of size $4\times 4$?

I believe they are, but I wanted to verify.

Comment: it is spelled nilpotent. What does "degree 2" mean?

Comment: @WillJagy $A^n=0$ is nilpotent of degree $n$ I was told earlier today

Comment: @WillJagy So here $A^2 = 0$ and I believe the matrices are the only matrices with (above as $A$) $A^2=0$

Comment: Alright, but given any invertible matrix $P,$ we get another matrix with the same characteristic and minimal polynomials from $P^{-1} A P.$ This other matrix may have quite a different appearance. You might experiment with $P$ a permutation matrix, each row and each column have only a single $1,$ all other entries are $0.$ Not too difficult to find $P^{-1}$

Comment: @WillJagy So looking at similar matrices to this one, I will find ones of a different form is what you are suggesting(or I have misinterpreted)

Comment: Correct.............. You will see this in a different way once you get to Jordan Normal Form. The overall answer is the same, though, all matrices with a given minimal polynomial $A^2$ of a fixed size are equivalent to certain Jordan forms.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you that makes sense, I will investigate

Comment: @WillJagy Is it possible you could give me a hint on what 'certain Jordan forms' you refer? The only eigenvalue is $0$, so we have $\lambda^n=0$ and I guess we have a matrix with $1$'s on all values above the primary diagonal? But this isn't nilpotent degree 2

Comment: The choices are two 2 by 2 Jordan blocks or a single 2 by 2 and a pair of 1 by 1's. So, either two ones in positions $1,2$ and $3,4,$ (they must be separated) or just one of those, everything else zero.

Comment: Oh, by $1,2$ I mean row 1, column 2. The other is row 3, column 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more forms. You will do well in considering Jordan blocks and in comparing the minimal polynomial to the characteristic polynomial.

One such example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&a&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\end{bmatrix}=0_{4\times 4}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the post means by "families". I assume it's about $4\times 4$ nilpotent matrices of degree $2$ up to similarity i.e., similarity class of matrices such that $A\neq \mathbf 0$ but $A^2=\mathbf 0$.

Read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4865457/955582) (and also the question post) for context.

Up to similarity, there are two $4\times 4$ matrices with degree of nilpotence $2$ corresponding to the partitions $2+2$ and $2+1+1$.

$\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &  & \\
0 & 0 &  & \\
 &  & 0 & 1\\
 &  & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &  & \\
0 & 0 &  & \\
 &  & 0 & \\
 &  &   & 0
\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$

All matrices in the described family are similar to one of these.

Note that the blank entries are zeroes.